# Which table is Custom Html stored in Joomla database?

Tags: joomla3.0

After I create a custom html module in Joomla, where is the html code stored in Joomla database?Appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it in the table `#___modules`, the field name is `content`; the `module` field will contain "mod_custom";

More params are stored as a json object in the `attribs` field.

Comment: I will check it in a while. Thank you so much for responding. If I could find it I will mark yours as answer. Really thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I found it. Thank you so much :) Have a nice day.